# drive not mounting after reboot despite good fstab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, fstab

I'm setting up a fresh Ubuntu 9.10 RC install.  This is the fstab entry for my functioning, healthy raid array:

```
# RAID storage drive
/dev/md0 /media/storage ext3 auto,rw,user,relatime,exec,async 0 3
```

I can manually mount and access /dev/md0, but /media/storage is not there after a reboot.  What gives?  This is the exact same fstab that works on a different boot partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahhh...I forgot to create the storage directory in the /media folder.  Problem solved once I did that.